# Separating consecutive nextLine(); inputs

Tags: java

New-bee in coding here, I was just wondering how to fix this. What happens is that when I run this snippet of code, I can only enter two inputs: a String, and a double, with the former getting assigned to setContactNum. Also, the program stops and fully compiles after I enter a digit (which is supposedly for setContactNum, but it gets assigned to setSalary), which is strange since I still have to enter an input for setDepartment.

```
if (input.toUpperCase().equals("E")) {
            
            System.out.println("Type employee's name, contact number, salary, and department. \nPress Enter for every input.");  
            employee.setName(sc.nextLine());
            employee.setContactNum(sc.nextLine());
            employee.setSalary(sc.nextDouble());
            employee.setDepartment(sc.nextLine());
        System.out.println("------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Name: " + employee.getName() + "\nContact number: " + employee.getContactNum() + "\nSalary: " + employee.getSalary() + "\nDepartment: " + employee.getDepartment());
        }
```

Can someone explain? Thank you so much!

I have tried using `System.out.println("")`; in between the `sc.nextLine()`'s and `sc.nextDouble()`'s, but to no avail.